# UIView in navigation controller goes upwards...?

Tags: iphone

i have attached as header one UIView(which has lot of buttons etc) in UITableViewController.i did not use table header.but when i scroll table view ,the header view (XIB file) goes upwards..can i stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create it inside the UITableViewController.  Create it outside and then you should get the desired behavior.